# How can I draw a half arrow with asterisks in java?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am in my first java class, and I am trying to draw a half arrow using asterisks. I am supposed to use a nested loop where the inner loop draws the *s and the outer loop iterates the number of times equal to the height of the arrow base. I have learned if-else, while loops, and for loops.

So far, I have been able to correctly draw the arrow for input values of
arrow base height: 5
arrow base width: 2
arrow head width: 4

When I try to add a while loop as the outer loop, the program times out. I am at a loss.

The next input I need to use is 2, 3, 4. My code gets the height of the base right (2), but not the width.

The last input I need is 3, 3, 7. My code gets none of that right at all. This is what I have so far.

What kind of loops should I be using to get the widths correct?

```
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  int arrowBaseHeight = 0;
  int arrowBaseWidth  = 0;
  int arrowHeadWidth = 0;
  int i = 0;

  System.out.println("Enter arrow base height: ");
  arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter arrow base width: ");
  arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter arrow head width: ");
  arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();


  for (i = 1; i <= arrowBaseHeight; ++i) {
      // Draw arrow base (height = 3, width = 2)
      System.out.println("**");
  }

  // Draw arrow head (width = 4)
  System.out.println("****");
  System.out.println("***");
  System.out.println("**");
  System.out.println("*");
```

Example of how the output arrow may look:

```
**
**
**
**
****
***
**
*
```

Comment: Your question is well worded, but could you show us what you are trying to draw?  Format it with 4 spaces of indentation.

Comment: If you look at the output statements at the end, I believe it would be something like this:http://pastebin.com/raw/hKu1Hxmp

Comment: Thank you! That is what my output should look like, depending on the number the user inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this problem, you would want to use for-loops since you know the exact number of times it should repeat. You know this because the user inputs the size of each part of the arrow.

```
Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);

int arrowBaseHeight = 0;
int arrowBaseWidth  = 0;
int arrowHeadWidth = 0;
int i = 0;

System.out.println("Enter arrow base height: ");
arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter arrow base width: ");
arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

System.out.println("Enter arrow head width: ");
arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();

//Your code above | Below is the modified code

String ast = ""; //String ast will contain how many asterisk we want for the base width;

for (int x = 1; x <= arrowBaseWidth; x++) //Loop forms the base width of the arrow
{
    ast += "*"; //This adds as many asterisks as we need to make the base width. SO if they enter 4, we get 4 *;
}


for (i = 1; i < arrowBaseHeight; ++i) 
{   
    System.out.println(ast); //Prints out the base width, which is now a String object
}

int tempHeadWidth = arrowHeadWidth; //Added this tempHeadWidth variable since we will be modifying it directly and 
                                    //we don't want to modify the original data and variable (it will cause problems if we do.

for (int y = 1; y <= arrowHeadWidth; y++) 
{
    for(int z = tempHeadWidth; z > 0; z--) //This loop prints the amount of asterisks we need per line in the arrowHead
    {
        System.out.print("*");
    } 
    // Once the loop above is finished, the rest of the code will execute in the main for-loop and then scheck if it will run again.
    tempHeadWidth -= 1; //So we are lowering the tempHeadWidth by one so the next time it enters 
                        //the nested (2nd) for loop it will be one asterisk smaller

    System.out.println(); //This makes a new line to keep adding more stars for the next row 
}
```

This method allows the user to input any size for the arrow (while staying in the value boundaries of an int of course)

Comment: Thank you so much! This has been causing a lot of stress for the past few days. Your explanation was great. The one thing that I had to change was < to <= in the second for loop, I'm not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

You have to make two nested loops. Inner loops will be printing characters in single line and outer loops will be printing multiple lines.

This is solution for your question with 'for' loops.

```
//printing arrow base
for (int h = 0; h < arrowBaseHeight; ++h)
{
  //printing single line - every line is the same
  for(int w = 0; w < arrowBaseWidth; w++)
    System.out.print("*");
  //finishing line
  System.out.println();
}

//printing arrow head
//starting with provided width and decreasing it with every iteration
for (int a = arrowHeadWidth; a > 0 ; a--)
{
  //printing single line - now every line is different
  //you have to count how many asterisks you are printing
  for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    System.out.print("*");
  //finishing line
  System.out.println();
}
```

You don't need to use brackets in loops if they contain only one line. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    System.out.print("*");
```

is equivalent to:

```
for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
{
    System.out.print("*");
}
```

Comment: You may want to throw some explaination into your code (and fix the indentation). The question mentions they're learning Java so shovelling them code isn't going to benefit them

Answer (score 1):

Could use two for the first to print the number of rows with the entered width entered using the [substring](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int)) method to capture the amount of printing `*`

then the second printing for the head of the arrow and go decreasing the width of the arrow

```
for (int i = 0;i < arrowBaseHeight; i++) 
 //when there is more than one instruction within a structure can be written without {}
    System.out.println("*************************".substring(0, arrowBaseWidth));

System.out.println("");
for (int i = arrowHeadWidth; i>=0; i-=1)  // head
    System.out.println("*************************".substring(0, i));
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but I am going through this same challenge on zybooks (which happens to be a lab activity). The above code marked solved is right but there are a few things that are off in the code that I thought I would clarify for everyone. Below is the code I used to pass 100%, and I will comment on the areas that needed to be modified. I also made the indentation a little easier to read. I hope this helps anyone needing a little push in the right direction.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawHalfArrow {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int arrowBaseHeight = 0;
      int arrowBaseWidth  = 0;
      int arrowHeadWidth = 0;

  System.out.println("Enter arrow base height: ");
  arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Enter arrow base width: ");
  arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

/* The while loop below needed to be added for the user input to make sure
** that their input never exceeded that of the arrowHeadWidth */

  while (arrowHeadWidth <= arrowBaseWidth) {
     System.out.println("Enter arrow head width: ");
     arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();
  }

  String ast = "";
  for (int x = 1; x <= arrowBaseWidth; x++) {
     ast+= "*";
  }

/* Here 'i' needed to be intialized as an integer ('int'). Also the '=' needed
** to be added to i<= arrowBaseHeight */

  for (int i = 1; i <= arrowBaseHeight; ++i) { 
        System.out.println(ast);
  }
  int tempHeadWidth = arrowHeadWidth;
  for (int y =1; y <= arrowHeadWidth; y++) {
     for (int z = tempHeadWidth; z > 0; z--) {
        System.out.print("*");
     }
     tempHeadWidth -= 1;
     System.out.println();
  }

  return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My Full Solution based off @dev joels answer

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawHalfArrow {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int arrowBaseHeight = 0;
      int arrowBaseWidth  = 0;
      int arrowHeadWidth = 0;

      System.out.println("Enter arrow base height: ");
      arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Enter arrow base width: ");
      arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();

      //System.out.println("Enter arrow head width: ");

      while (arrowHeadWidth <= arrowBaseWidth) {
        System.out.println("Enter arrow head width: ");
        arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();
      }       

      for (int h = 0; h < arrowBaseHeight; ++h) {
         for(int w = 0; w < arrowBaseWidth; w++) 
            System.out.print("*");
        System.out.println();
      }

       for (int a = arrowHeadWidth; a > 0 ; a--) {
          for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
             System.out.print("*");
         System.out.println();
       }
      return;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class DrawHalfArrow {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
      int arrowBaseHeight;
      int arrowBaseWidth;
      int arrowHeadWidth;
      
      System.out.println("Enter arrow base height:");
      arrowBaseHeight = scnr.nextInt();
      
      System.out.println("Enter arrow base width:");
      arrowBaseWidth = scnr.nextInt();
      
      
      do {
         System.out.println("Enter arrow head width:");
         arrowHeadWidth = scnr.nextInt();
      } while (arrowHeadWidth <= arrowBaseWidth); 
      
      System.out.println("");
      
      // Draw arrow base 
      int row;
      int column;
      for (row = 0; row < arrowBaseHeight; ++row) {
         for (column = 0; column < arrowBaseWidth; ++column) {
            System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println("");
      }
            
      // Draw arrow head 
      for (row = 0; row < arrowHeadWidth; ++row) {
         int thisRowWidth = arrowHeadWidth - row;
         for (column = 0; column < thisRowWidth; ++column) {
            System.out.print("*");
         }
         System.out.println("");
      }
            
   }
}
```